# Swapping Rows in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a function that moves rows of a table up by one row at a time. The down button has not been made, as I am first trying to build the up. Though the function does make a row move, it often skips over some rows, moving two spots up, often straight to the top of the table. The last row added always seems to move as expected (1 up at a time). The Up function is at the very bottom of my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/9/). Does it have to do with how I created each row? the JS String?

Also, given the up and down functions will only move a row one way either way, would it be better to just switch the innerHTML for the two rows being swapped (although I think my previous and next row errors would still exist)?

```
function Up() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
         row.next().after(row);
    else
         row.prev().before(row);
}
```

I'm also fairly sure, it never recognizes that it hasClass('up') (whether its 'up' or btnUp').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's a much better solution which only requires you to bind once, plus reduces your code size. Btw, jQuery provides since version 1.7 a preferred alternative to `.bind()` which is `.on()`. Instead of binding multiple events to all buttons in your table, you should **delegate events**, thereby reducing the amount of listeners to only 4 for the entire table AND eliminating the need for rebinding/unbinding!

```
$("#tblData").on("click", ".btnEdit", Edit);     
$("#tblData").on("click", ".btnDelete", Delete); 
$("#tblData").on("click", ".btnUp", Up); 
$("#tblData").on("click", ".btnSave", Save);
```

The code above tells Javascript: "Inside `#tblData`, execute `<function>` only if the target (=the button clicked) has class `btnSomething`." In your fiddle, I also passed `event (e)` as a parameter and replaced `$(this)` with `$(e.target)`. It's optional but good practice.

I also simplified your up function to:

```
function Up(e) {
    var row = $(e.target).parent().parent(); //tr
    if (row.prev().length)
        row.prev().before(row);
}
```

The result: less code, better performance, cleaner. http://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/10/

Answer (score 1):

In your Edit and Add functions you need to unbind event handlers before rebinding them.

```
$(".btnEdit").unbind().bind("click", Edit); 
$(".btnDelete").unbind().bind("click", Delete); 
$(".btnUp").unbind().bind("click", Up);
```

Without unbinding them, multiple instances of those functions get bound to those elements (because the $(".btnUp") selector selects every instance of an element with the btnUp class).

So after adding 4 items.  The first would have 4 instances of the up() function, the second would have 3, the third would have 2, and the last would have 1 (Which is why the last one was the only one working as intended).

Edit:

A potentially better way would be to only bind the functions to one element when needed.  You can do this by editing the binding on the save function like:

```
par.find("td > .btnEdit").bind("click", Edit); 
par.find("td > .btnDelete").bind("click", Delete); 
par.find("td > .btnUp").bind("click", Up);
```

And on the Edit function you only need to bind the save button:

```
$(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer Coleen, but @Tyblitz has a better answer you might want to accept instead :)